# laravel & vuejs: Builder could not be converted to string

Tags: laravel, vue.js

this is my search function in users controller

```
public function search()
{
    if( $search = \Request::get('q') ){
        $users = User::where( function($query) use ($search){
                $query->where('name','LIKE',"%$search%");
        });
    }
    return $users;

}
```

this is the vuejs code .Fire is new instance of vuejs that i created in app.js

```
Fire.$on('searching',() => {
  let query = this.$parent.search; // query parent(app.js) for 'search'
      axios.get('api/findUser?q='+query)
           .then((data) => {
                  this.users = data.data;
                })
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

You've constructed a query, but you haven't actually *run* it until you call `->get()` on it.

```
return $users->get();
```